# query to get data from multiple table only if available else get as null

Tags: mysql, database

The below query satisfies the requirement only if there is data in all the mentioned tables because the "AND" is used and "AND" truth table specifies if all condition are true the it provides the output else it does not give the output.

But if there is no data in one of the depended table then the query returns no output only because of the "AND" function.

Need help to use "OR" instead of "AND" so that if any of the depended table does not have any data it should return as null/NA.

```
   SELECT a.id, 
       a.userId, 
       a.trainerName, 
       a.bioDescription, 
       a.trainingCategories, 
       a.preferredWorkouts, 
       a.gymAccess, 
       a.gymLocation, 
       a.equipments, 
       a.perSession, 
       a.groupSession, 
       a.virtualSession, 
       a.sessionPacks,
       b.id, 
       b.username, 
       b.profileImg, 
       c.trainerId, 
       AVG(c.ratings) as avgRatings, 
       count(d.trainerId) as totalSessions
FROM trainerProfile a, users b, trainerFeedback c, allEvents d
WHERE a.id = 1 AND a.userId = b.id AND a.id = c.trainerId;
```

Comment: You are using aggregate functions without group by. And you should switch to proper join syntax

Comment: It would be better if you add data examples and expected result, a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0) would be great

Answer (score 1):

You need to use left join and group by

```
   SELECT 
       a.id, 
       a.userId, 
       a.trainerName, 
       a.bioDescription, 
       a.trainingCategories, 
       a.preferredWorkouts, 
       a.gymAccess, 
       a.gymLocation, 
       a.equipments, 
       a.perSession, 
       a.groupSession, 
       a.virtualSession, 
       a.sessionPacks,
       b.id, 
       b.username, 
       b.profileImg, 
       c.trainerId, 
       AVG(c.ratings) as avgRatings, 
        as totalSessions,
       d.tid AS trainerId
FROM trainerProfile a
LEFT JOIN users b ON a.userId = b.id
LEFT JOIN trainerFeedback c ON a.id = c.trainerId
CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(trainerId) tid FROM allEvents) d
WHERE a.id = 1 
GROUP BY
       a.userId, 
       a.trainerName, 
       a.bioDescription, 
       a.trainingCategories, 
       a.preferredWorkouts, 
       a.gymAccess, 
       a.gymLocation, 
       a.equipments, 
       a.perSession, 
       a.groupSession, 
       a.virtualSession, 
       a.sessionPacks,
       b.id, 
       b.username, 
       b.profileImg, 
       c.trainerId, 
       d.tid 
ORDER BY
       a.id,
       a.userId;
```

Comment: Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'd.trainerId' in 'field list'

Comment: Corrected : sorry about that.

Comment: I am getting the same error yet. Have I missed something? its not corrected/updated.